# error using PCA opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pca

I am trying to get PCA object in real time. I am using opencv 3.0 and c++. When I run, it shows the result but there is come up such error. Here code from opencv :

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

and the error message :

> openCV Error:Assertion failed (dims <=2 && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned) size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType(_Tp)::channels) ...

the error message show up on command windows

does anyone have ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You're passing matrices of wrong dimensions. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Actually nothing wrong with my code when I compile, but error will show up when I run my code. However I still can get my result.